# Wordpress - moving to production server issue

Tags: php, wordpress, ftp, themes

I planned to move my Wordpress site from my Xampp server to my production server. I changed the address under the 'Administration - Settings - General' panel. However, unfortunately I was not able to move the actual files to the new location via ftp, as my hosting network appears to be down.

I want to continue working on the project in my local server, however, when I tried to access the WP-admin login screen to login to my site, it automatically redirected me to the newly specified address of the site (which is currently empty).

I am now stuck outside, unable to log into my site. Has a constant been changed somewhere, or does anyone have a fix where I could somehow undo the changes that I have made?

Thanks!

Best Regards,

Robert Young
London, UK.

Comment: Have you checked your wp-config.php?

Comment: Thanks - which constant should I check? The 'db_name' is still 'localhost'.

Answer (score 0):

You can re-set the correct URL working on the MySql DB. In the table "wp_options" you can find "option_name = 'www.example.com';".

Answer (score 0):

Here is a nice free plugin which handles moving Wordpress sites from one host to another:

https://wordpress.org/plugins/duplicator/

It is an easy way to complete the job, without having to get your hands "dirty" with database and configuration files modifications. Hope this helps!